# Copying elements of a linked list to another linked list in reverse order in C

Tags: c, linked-list, reverse, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I'm new to programming in C and taking a course. I'm having trouble with one of the tasks I'm practicing. I'm supposed to Write a program that creates a linked list of 10 characters, then creates a copy of the list in reverse order. I have written (mostly copied) a code, but it only reverses the contents of my linked list, doesn't copy them to a new linked list in reverse order. It's also not working with letters even though I'm using char data type. works fine with numbers.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct Node
{
    char data;
    struct Node *next;
};

static void reverse(struct Node **head_ref)
{
    struct Node *previous = NULL;
    struct Node *current = *head_ref;
    struct Node *next;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        next = current->next;
        current->next = previous;
        previous = current;
        current = next;
    }
    *head_ref = previous;
}

void push(struct Node **head_ref, char new_data)
{
    struct Node *new_node =
        (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->data = new_data;
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);
    (*head_ref) = new_node;
}

void printList(struct Node *head)
{
    struct Node *temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct Node *head = NULL;
    char element = NULL;
    printf("Enter 10 characters:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        scanf_s("%d", &element);
        push(&head, element);
    }
 
    printf("Given linked list\n");
    printList(head);
    reverse(&head);
    printf("\nReversed Linked list \n");
    printList(head);
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: If you need to create a reverse copy, then treat it as a *stack*. That will make the reversing rather trivial.

Comment: The reason why it is "not working with characters" is that you are reading the elements as integers in `scanf_s("%d", &element);`.

Comment: Talking about stacks, you already work with the original list as a stack, even having a `push` function. Why not use that existing function to add elements to the reversed copy?

Answer (score 3):

This for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{
    scanf_s("%d", &element);
    push(&head, element);
}
```

invokes undefined behavior because there is used an incorrect conversion specifier `%d` with an object of the type `char`,

You need to write

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{
    scanf_s( " %c", &element, 1 );
    push(&head, element);
}
```

Pay attention to the blank before the conversion specifier `%c` in the format string. This allows to skip white space characters in the input stream.

As for the function then it can be declared and defined the following simple way using the function `push` that you already defined

```
struct Node * reverse_copy( const struct Node *head )
{
    struct Node *new_head = NULL;

    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        push( &new_head, head->data );
    }

    return new_head;
}
```

And in main you can write something like

```
struct Node *second_head = reverse_copy( head );
```

Take into account that the function `push` would be more safer if it would process the situation when memory allocation for a node failed.

Answer (score 2):

To create a copy in reverse order, create a new list with the same values as the original list but prepend the new nodes using the `push` function.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    char data;
    struct Node *next;
};

void prepend(struct Node **head_ref, char new_data) {
    struct Node *new_node = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->data = new_data;
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);
    (*head_ref) = new_node;
}

void append(struct Node **head_ref, char new_data) {
    struct Node *new_node = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node *node = *head_ref;
    new_node->data = new_data;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    if (!node) {
        *head_ref = new_node;
    } else {
        while (node->next)
            node = node->next;
        node->next = new_node;
    }
}

void printList(const struct Node *head) {
    const struct Node *temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("%c ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

struct Node *copy_reverse(struct Node *list) {
    struct Node *new_list = NULL;
    while (list) {
        prepend(&new_list, list->data);
        list = list->next;
    }
    return new_list;
}

void freeList(struct Node *list) {
    while (list) {
        struct Node *node = list;
        list = list->next;
        free(node);
    }
}

int main() {
    struct Node *head = NULL;
    char element;
    printf("Enter 10 characters:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        scanf_s("%c", &element);
        push(&head, element);
    }
 
    printf("Given linked list\n");
    printList(head);

    struct Node *copy = copy_reverse(head);
    printf("\nReversed Linked list \n");
    printList(copy);
    freeList(head);
    freeList(copy);
    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.  All it needs is one tweak.  In `reverse`, you need to create a new copy of the `current` node and use that instead.  Also, since you'll be ending up with a second list and not altering the original, you should return the new list from `reverse`.

```c
static struct Node* reverse(const struct Node* head_ref)
{
    struct Node* previous = NULL;
    const struct Node* current = head_ref;
    struct Node* copy;

    while (current != NULL) {
        copy = malloc(sizeof(*copy));
        if (copy == NULL) {
            // handle error
        }
        copy->data = current->data;
        copy->next = previous;
        previous = copy;
        current = current->next;
    }

    return previous;
}
```

You can also make the loop prettier by converting it to a `for` loop.

```c
for (current = head_ref; current != NULL; current = current->next) {
```

Finally, when you print out the list, you're using `%d` in the `printf` format string.  `%d` will print the `char` as an integer.  To print out the actual character, use `%c` instead.